# How to remove visualforce page default tooltip

Tags: visualforce

In my visual force page where ever I place the cursor it is showing the page name as the tooltip(title).Its really annoying.

How to remove it...???

My Vf page name is Support First,in that page am having 2 to 3 page block tables.

[image: this is the tooltip i need to remove]

In this screen shot i just placed cursor on a pageblock section

code sample:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Block Title">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dataItems}" var="c"
        title="Cause Validation" id="pg_block_tab2" frame="box" border="0">
         <apex:column id="hintColId" headerValue="Question" title="{!c.plainText}" value="{!c.data.Question__c}" />

          <apex:column headerValue="Answer">
                <apex:selectRadio value="{! c.answer}" borderVisible="false" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </apex:column>

           <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="2" headerValue="Hint" >
             <div id="{!c.data.Name}" class="hider">   
                     <apex:outputText value="{!c.data.Name}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
               </div>  
            </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

likewise i have 2 more pageblock sections in my page.

Thanks
Chitra

Comment: can you share your vf page code and possibly a screenshot of your page with the tooltip ?

Comment: Are you having any javascript libraries on the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `helptext` tag in your VF page then just remove it and you should be all set.

Here is ex that will show Help text .

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Contact.Fields.New_Agency_Name__c.inlineHelpText}" >
```

Here is example that will NOT show Help text .

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

If you problem still perstist please provide screen shot(with tool tip) of your VF page .

Comment: Hi AtulRaj,
Thank you for your quick reply..I just edited my original post with the screen shot..please have look and give me your ideas..

Comment: Do u have helpText in your VF page?

Comment: If not share your code too. May be you have Javascript that is showing Tooltip.

Comment: I have added screen shot and sample code with the main post..please have a look..

Comment: the screen shot and code looks unrelated. in screenshot you have Question, Answer & escalate button but in code you have Analyse Case button. This does not make sense. We do not need the exact code from your production. just abstract working code and related screen shot will help.

Comment: Hi AtulRaj, Sorry for the wrong code and thanks for your time..I just edited the original post with my exact code..I think the code size is limited..I have added the button code also.But it is not taking that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16769/discussion-between-chitra-thambirajan-and-atulrajguru9).